# How to determine locality of HDFS file for use in Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, celery, hdfs, mapr

I have a system that runs Python tasks across a compute cluster using Celery to manage the queue.  These tasks operate on data stored in MapR-FS (which exposes the Hadoop HFDS API, so things techniques that work on Hadoop HDFS *should* work on MapR-FS).

I'd like to be able to determine the locality of a file stored in MapR-FS, and assign the task to run on a specific cluster node that has local access to the file.

Is this possible?

Comment: The celery side is done; I have the infrastructure already in place to assign tasks to specific nodes and workers.

Comment: I don't know mapr-fs but does `readlink -f filename` tell you the correct volume where the file is located? Alternatively what about `df `readlink -f filename` | tail -1 | awk '{ print $6 }'`?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but that doesn't work. All files on mapr-fs are on one volume that is distributed across mulitple disks and compute nodes.

Comment: @MichaelMoore Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @MattK Nope.  Never did.